# offsetof and sizeof like functionality for bit fields

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

There is `offsetof` macro and `sizeof` operator for structs and classes. 

Is there any way to get similar functionality for **bit fields** so that the **bit offset** and **bit size** of bit field members can be queried?

The `sizeof` could be emulated using `#define field_name_size n`, but for `offsetof` I am afraid it would become too cumbersome to use `#define field_name_offset`, since then one seems to have to use some complex formula for considering all preceding members in the bit field.

In certain cases it would enable one to overcome the need to manually keep the code in sync with bit field definitions, which is failure-prone. 

One example would be interlocked writes to members of bit fields, where one needs to use custom function for writing to such members, since compiler does not offer such.

Additionally, I understand that compilers may implement bit field layout a bit differently. Availability of such macros/operators would reduce the impact of that problem too.

Comment: _"Is there any way to get similar functionality for bit fields so that the bit offset and bit size of bit field members can be queried?"_ I'm not aware of one.

Comment: The really messy part is that the C specification allows bit fields to span multiple storage units. So on a 32-bit system  `struct { int x:20, y:20, z:20; }` can occupy either 2 ints or 3 ints.

Comment: A prominent example where this fails is the `std::vector<bool>` specialization.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to get similar functionality for bit fields so that the bit offset and bit size of bit field members can be queried?

No, there isn't a way to achieve this. Bit size offsets can't be deduced from bitfield members.

Also `sizeof()` will always return size of the underlying type, the minimum is `char`, thus 1 is the minimum size you'll retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not. And this is one of the many reasons you should avoid bitfields and do your own bit arrays and similar using arithmetic and full, addressable integer types.

Answer (score 1):

[@Victor Suarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799006/victor-suarez) has created a sweet [constexpr solution prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70558501/480393) where he creates a union of the type and a long long, and then manipulates the bitfield and searches for the effect in long long.  he draft is incomplete, for example it should use some u8[sizeof(T)] instead of a long long and should search for the manipulated bits in there, but it shows:  it's possible and it essentially works/will work.

Alas, I don't have the chance to create a full portable *solution* at this time, but I wanted to point to a solution approach.

Comment: Since this is only a link to another answer, it should have been a comment. Also, the linked answer has some issues pointed out in comments there. It isn't at all portable, and type punning isn't even legal in C++ (even if many compilers do support it).

Comment: @adabsurdum: The question is tagged C as well as C++, and it is legal in C if you do it right. I don't see any basis for complaining that this "should have been a comment". If it provides an answer to the question and isn't just discussion that could reasonably be deleted without loss of value, **semantically it is an answer**.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE -- but it doesn't provide an answer, it provides a link to another SO answer written by someone else. I mention C++ because both this answerer and the original answerer are talking about C++. The only issues I see for C are potential padding issues and that the _real_ answer is using built-in compiler functions (hence my portability comment). None of this is apparent unless you go and read the linked answer which this answer merely points to.

Comment: the question is tricky; the answer was "no" 7 years ago, before constexpr everything; the question is "is there a way", technically, not "give me the exact solution"; and I reference a path to the solution because I don't have the two days to create a complete, portable, correct solution.  furthermore I add to the referenced approach by pointing out you need a union not with a u64 or u128 but with a u8[] (uint8_t[]), and you need to do more.  and then it _will_ be portable if you stick with constexpr.

Comment: @SusanneOberhauser -- the answer posted here does not seem to add these things that you suggest. This answer says nothing of `u64`, `u128`, `u8[]`, or `uint8_t[]`; it does suggest that the _other_ answer uses `unsigned[]`, which it does not, and neither does it use `constexpr`. It isn't clear from your answer how `constexpr` is significant. Your answer here just says that interested parties should go read the other answer (which has its own issues, but that isn't really the point). If your answer _here_ could stand on its own I would not have complained.

Comment: I get what you're saying.  I really do.  it's unsatisfactory for me as well.  I've fixed the obvious error (indeed _I_ speak about some u8[], not the thing I'm pointing to).

and all other attempts at answering (the siblings to my not-solution-but-at-least-solution-approach so to speak) claim it's impossible, which is what I thought as well, until this afternoon... heck I've even looked up that "-1" is portable C++ for "all ones" these days.  This approach will work.

Comment: Although this approach involves representational details which the compiler does have to match up between compile-time `consteval` logic and runtime code, nonetheless it likely isn't valid to do in a `consteval` or `constexpr` function.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26201529/103167   `std::bit_cast` may eventually provide a solution but current compilers have problems with that, too https://stackoverflow.com/q/76932233/103167

Comment: @adabsurdum: If the linked method were not on SO but some other site, I don't think you would have that objection. The author of this answer briefly explained the method (that's an answer to the question here, not the linked question) and cited the source of information where they learned the method and where the reader can get more information. **This is an excellent form for an answer!!**

Comment: @BenVoigt TIL [bit_cast vs unions for type punning](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun) nice.  also somewhere else I figured in C you don't have constexpr functions (in theory) but it works (in practice).  like union based punning...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE -- _"... I don't think you would have that objection."_ You are wrong about this; I would still have the same objection. **_"This is an excellent form for an answer!!"_** You and I are of different opinions on this, but bolded double exclamation point shouting does not seem like a convincing way to move opinions in your direction. Please, no need to respond further.